# 2D array manipulation with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to manipulate some 2D array using pointers, I know the basics of pointers but I am having difficulties with this code :

```
{
    

    char a[3][10] = { "Malek", "Zied","Nicolas" };
    char* ptr = a;

    char c = *(*(a + 1) + 1);
    char r = *(ptr + 1)+1;
    printf("i from Zied is %c :\n", c);
    printf("i from zied is also : %c", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Now ptr contains the adress of a so I don't understand why the `*(ptr + 1)+1` give back a char and not an adress. should not `a` and `ptr` be similar in this case ? how are : `* (* (a + 1) + 1)` and `(* (ptr + 1)+1)` not the same and also `* (ptr + 1)+1` and `* ( *(a + 1) + 1)` the same ? Thanks in advance

Comment: The line `char* ptr = a;` is invalid, because the expression `a` [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer to the first element of the array `a` and therefore has type `char(*)[10]` (pointer to an array of 10 elements of type `char`), whereas `ptr` is of type `char*` (pointer to `char`). Since both pointers are of different type, the assignment is invalid (unless you use an explicit cast). Your compiler should be at least giving you a warning about this invalid line.

Comment: This distinction is important, because pointer arithmetic is performed in units of the type that it points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler should issue a message for the declaration of the pointer `ptr`:

```
char a[3][10] = { "Malek", "Zied","Nicolas" };
char* ptr = a;
```

because the type of the pointer `ptr` and the pointer type of the initializing expression are not compatible and there is no implicit conversion between the pointer types. The array `a` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `char ( * )[10]` while the initialized pointer `ptr` has the type `char *`.

You should write:

```
char a[3][10] = { "Malek", "Zied","Nicolas" };
char* ptr = ( char * )a;
```

That is in this initialization the two-dimensional array is interpreted as a one-dimensional array and the pointer `ptr` now points to the character `'M'` of the first "row" of the two-dimensional array `a`.

In fact the above declaration of the pointer `ptr` is equivalent to:

```
char* ptr = &a[0][0];
```

Thus the expression `ptr + 1` points to the second character (`a[0][1]`) that is to the character `'a'` of the string "Malek". Dereferencing the pointer expression `*( ptr + 1 )` you get the pointed character `'a'` and adding `1` to the character `'a'` `*(ptr + 1)+1` you get the character `'b'`.

In fact this expression `*(ptr + 1)+1` is equivalent to `p[1] + 1`.

As for this expression `*(*(a + 1) + 1)` then as it was already mentioned the `a` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element ("row") of the type `char ( * )[10]`. The expression `a + 1` points to the second "row" of the array that is to the second element of the array. The expression `*( a + 1 )` yields lvalue of the of the one-dimensional array of the type `char[10]` that is the second "row" of the array `a`.

In this expression `*(a + 1) + 1` the expression `*( a + 1 )` is in turn implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `char *`. That is the expression of the type `char[10]` is converted to an expression of the type `char *` that points to the first character of the second "row". So the whole expression points to the second character of the second "row" that is to the character `'i'`  Dereferencing the pointer expression you get this character `'i'`.

And this expression `*(*(a + 1) + 1)` is equivalent to `a[1][1]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a small question : `char* ptr = &a[0][0];` can be written as `char**ptr = &a[0]`  right ? Such as the double pointer ptr contains the address of the first 1D array of 10 elements. I can also use `ptr + `  to simply point to the second 1D array and finally use `*(ptr+1)`  or `ptr[1] ` to point to the first element of the second 2D array and finally `ptr[1][1]` or `*(*(ptr+1))`  to access its content, but it can't be changed to another value  due to the fact that we have a string lateral here,. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Malek The expression a[0] has the type char[10]. So the expression &a[0] has the type char ( * )[10]. It is not the same as char **.

Answer (score 0):

pointer arithmetic won't work with arrays. pointers and arrays are not the same. [read this](https://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html)

Comment: You should reread my answer.:) I hope it will be useful for you.:)

Comment: with char *ptr = ( char * )a; you did type casting, i know this. That works.